# How to add columns from a Common Table to New Table in Enterprise Architect

Tags: javascript, vbscript, enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect 10 tool for design schema for SQL Database.

Every time a new table is added to EA Schema (lets say with columns 'Name' and 'Description'), common columns (UserId, Status, Role, 15 such columns) has to be added to the new table.

Destination table columns = Source table columns + Common table Columns.

The Destination table shall have the columns - Name, Description, UserId, Status and Role.

I have more than 100 tables and can't add manually all the common columns to each table.

Is there any provision or scripting (javascript or vbscript) can perform this action when I add new table and execute the script ?

-- Added this code after trying...

```
!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-JScript
```

/*
 * Script Name: 
 * Author: 
 * Purpose: 
 * Date: 
 */

function main()
{
    // TODO: Enter script code here!
    // Show the script output window
    Repository.EnsureOutputVisible( "Script" );

```
// Get the currently selected element in the tree to work on
var theElement as EA.Element;
var theDestElement as EA.Element;

theElement = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
//theDestElement = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
//theDestElement.Name='Newtable1';

if( theElement != null && theElement.ObjectType == otElement)
{

    Session.Output( "Working on element '" + theElement.Name + "' (Type=" + theElement.Type +
        ", ID=" + theElement.ElementID + ")" );



    var srcAttributes as EA.Collection;
    srcAttributes = theElement.Attributes;

    theDestElement = Repository.
    Session.Output(theDestElement);
    theDestElement.Name='NewTable1';
    var dstAttributes as EA.Collection;
    dstAttributes = theDestElement.Attributes;

    newAttribute = null;

    // List attributes
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < srcAttributes.Count ; i++ )
    {
        var currentAttribute as EA.Attribute;
        currentAttribute = srcAttributes.GetAt( i );
        dstAttributes.AddNew(currentAttribute.,currentAttribute);
        //theDestElement


        Session.Output( "Attribute: " + currentAttribute.Name  );
    }

    Session.Output( "Done!" );

}

else
{
    // No item selected in the tree, or the item selected was not an element
    Session.Prompt( "This script requires an element be selected in the Project Browser.\n" +
        "Please select an element in the Project Browser and try again.", promptOK );
}
```

}

main();

I could able to select all the attributes of one table using

```
theElement = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
```

but the destination table to which all the attributes to be copied is unclear to me.

Please help.

Thank you,
Ramm

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you could have used a **template package**, where your common table with columns is placed.

TO do it retrospectively, you can achieve it using a the internal scripting support. Goto Tools-> Scripting in EA and look for "VBScript - Attribute Lifecycle Example" or 'JScript - Attribute Lifecycle Example' to see how attributes are added / removed from an element.